Get rendered HTML from an external page with Node.JS
I'm trying to build a multi-search tool that searches a list of websites and outputs results from all of them on one page as an array.
The NPM package node-fetch works fine for most of the sites: fetch the desired URL, send the HTML to the front end and then use a DOM Parser to search through the HTML for the elements I want to extract data from.
Now, the last site I'm trying to search has un-rendered content which appears in the fetched HTML as {{Title}} for example instead of the actual text title which I want to extract.
I realise the content is unrendered so after some searching I found Puppeteer and I'm trying to use it as below:
const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto(url)
const HTML = await page.content()
await browser.close()

However, the output HTML variable still contains the un-rendered content.
I saw another StackOverflow post that recommended changing line 3 to this: await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle' }) however this just throws Error: Unknown value for options.waitUntil: networkidle.
Any help appreciated.

It's networkidle0 or networkidle2, where the number determines how many in-flight requests are allowed before resolving. So networkidle0 means it'll block until there are 0 live requests. Please see the docs. That said, networkidle is discouraged. If you don't mind sharing the site and expected output, there's probably faster and more reliable way to get the data. See also Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded.

@ggorlen unfortunately neither networkidle0 or networkidle2 work. Neither do any of the waitFor commands, nor does setTimeout.

Well, at least they're valid options. Without the site and expected output, I can't help you further, unfortunately. Maybe you're being blocked as a bot by Cloudflare, the element you want is in an iframe or shadow root, or you're choosing an incorrect selector to pass to waitForSelector()--it's anyone's guess.

@ggorlen I'd prefer not to post it on here but can PM you if possible

There are no PMs on SO and I can only provide public help here, but if you leave it in a comment, you can delete the comment in a minute or so. I won't use it in the answer. Better yet, if you can recreate the failing behavior with a custom site, then you can share that. This would be fully reproducible and most useful for future visitors (granted, many sites have weird behavior that's hard to replicate, particularly cloudflare blocks--you might be able to find a similar site that has close enough behavior though).

You may want to [edit] your post to remove the networkidle question--I think we've resolved that part of it, and maybe show some site-agnostic attempt at using wait for selectors or one of the valid networkidle options. This will give my answer a bit more context and make the question less trivially a typo issue. Also, please let me know if my answer works for you or not when you have a chance.

networkidle is not an option--it's either networkidle0 or networkidle2 depending on how many in-flight requests you want to allow before resolving.
But networkidle is not a good way to wait for particular data to load. It's very pessimistic, waiting for a bunch of resources that you don't care about. Networkidle can time out if too many requests stay unresolved for too long. It's mainly suitable for screenshots, not scraping text.
Generally, wait for a response to arrive or a DOM node to exist. "domcontentloaded" is the fastest and most reliable load condition Puppeteer currently supports, generally the one to use.
Responses are often easier and more reliable to scrape than the DOM. The site you're automating sends a request to /api/search and receives a JSON response containing the data you want. You can intercept this response with waitForResponse and grab the JSON payload without touching the document:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.7.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  const url = "<Your URL>";
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const res = await page.waitForResponse(res =>
    res.url().endsWith("/api/search")
  );
  const {data: {dataset}} = await res.json();
  console.log(dataset.map(e => ({price: e.price, vrn: e.vrn})));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

One advantage here is you get all of the data you might ever want, including prices in raw, unformatted form.
But using the document isn't too bad here either, assuming the selectors don't change:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  const url = "<Your URL>";
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForFunction(`
    document.querySelectorAll(".price-details").length > 1
  `);
  const data = await page.$$eval(".featured-item", els => els.map(e => ({
    plate: e.querySelector(".btn-plate").textContent.trim(),
    price: e.querySelector(".price-details").textContent.trim(),
  })));
  console.log(data.filter(e => !e.plate.includes("{{")));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

The quirk handled here is that the site loads with a template similar to <div class="price-details">{{Price}}</div>, so the standard waitForSelector(".price-details") would resolve prematurely. waitForFunction is used instead to block until there's more than just the template on the page. Later, the template is filtered out of the results.
Disclosure: I'm the author of the linked blog post.

You are a hero. Your time is muchly appreciated :)
